# use Remmina Remote Desktop Client to access raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use Remmina Remote Desktop Client on my Ubuntu (a virtual machine I installed on my mac) to remote control raspberry pi. But when I finished the profile settings and double-clicked on it, a window showing "Unable to connect to VNC server" popped out. Does anyone know what might be the possible for this? This is my first time trying to access Raspberry pi using VNC.

Comment: Do you have a vnc server running on the raspberry pi with an open vnc port?

Comment: Oh it seems to be the problem. I forget to install vnc server on my pi. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the RPi and the Ubuntu machine are on the same network

***On the RPi***

1) `sudo raspi-config` > Interfaces > enable VNC

2) `reboot`

3) `ifconfig` to get the IP address of RPI

***On the Ubuntu machine***

1) Open remmina make a new VNC connection

2) Enter RPi IP address, and/or user name

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have a vnc server running on the pi as Noz said. The following steps are how I set up my vnc server whenever I get a new pi/re-setup an old one:

1. `sudo apt-get install x11vnc`
2. `x11vnc -storepasswd` then enter your password, skip if you don't want one
3. `cd /home/pi/.config`
4. If there is an autostart folder, `cd autostart`. If there is no autostart folder, `mkdir autostart`, then `cd autostart`
5. `sudo nano x11vnc.desktop`

   - Enter the following lines in the file (no spaces by equals signs)
     `[Desktop Entry]
     Encoding=UTF-8
     Type=Application
     Name=X11VNC
     Comment=
     Exec=x11vnc -forever -usepw -display :0 -ultrafilexfer
     StartupNotify=false
     Terminal=false
     Hidden=false`

I don't use remmina as my client, but once that is done you should be able to connect, and the VNC Host:Display info for me is `raspberrypi:0`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the problem :)   I followed the instruction on the official website [raspberry](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) to set up vncserver on my pc but still failed the connection.   I got this when I execute the vnc shell on my pi:   ```Warning: raspberrypi:0 is taken because of /tmp/.X0-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server raspberrypi:0
A VNC server is already running as :0
```  The connection still failed after having done all these.

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have a vnc server? otherwise try deleting that file I guess

Comment: I think I connect to my pi now after deleting the files. But the screen is like this  [here_goes_the_image](https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1452/23678826543_51d886b6bd_z.jpg) Maybe there are still some problems on the server side.